# I cannot load Matlab generated binary image .mat file larger than 2GB in TensorFloor using python3 and hdf5storage.loadmat

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, binary-data

I am importing binary image matrix generated in Matlab into python3 script to run TensorFlow with Keras. The image matrix is greater than 2GB, it is 4 dimensional. I can load in in Matlab through command window:

```
>> load('imageMatrix.mat')
>> size(imageMatrix)
ans =
     200         200           1       60000
```

I am getting error when I run both python script and notebook files:
`TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

Is it possible to import such a matrix greater than 2GB to TensorFlow with Keras?

I tried to load it in Jupyter notebook using "hdf5storage" and got the error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`

```
import hdf5storage
#imageMatrix =hdf5storage.loadmat('imageMatrix.mat') 
hdf5storage.loadmat('imageMatrix.mat')
shapeOfImagaMatrix=np.shape(imageMatrix)
plt.imshow(imageMatrix[:,:,1,15])
plt.savefig('Visul_Image_M=80.pdf')
```

Comment: You might be running into some limitation of the software. 2 GiB files were rather uncommon not so long ago... What exact machine (32/64 bit), operating system, software versions?

Comment: Please include full code and tracebacks, loading files > 2GB works fine with HDF5. I do it every day.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comments. I couldn't figure out how to attach files here. Is there any way that could share my files or email?

Comment: Ubuntu was updated recently to latest version on my workstation, It is 64 bit. TensorFlow and Keras are latest stable versions.  I can't check what exact versions are they; another software is running on Windows right now.

Comment: Matlab generated binary matrix is of size [200 200 1 60000]. I can load it on MATLAB through command window. Matlab also produces error if I try loading it in mlx file. Before running mlx file I load data first. I am not sure how to do it in TensorFlow. I tried to open it in Jupyter notebook and python script. Both producing error loading binary image matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The third dimension of the value of `imageMatrix['imageMatrix']` appears to only have a length of 1, so it seems like the fix here is to index it via `imageMatrix['imageMatrix'][:,:,0,15]`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking to see if the `loadmat()` function returns a dictionary with a key to pull out the image? I know when loading in tables of values this can be a problem if the table variable in MATLAB has a distinct name. In that case, the returned value from `loadmat()`, in this case `imageMatrix` would have a key to pull out the data.

If this is indeed what is occurring, one can print out the keys by calling `.keys()` on the returned value.